# Can I build SearchPredicates in HibernateSearch without SearchSession and Class?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am trying to migrate a project using ElasticSearch to HibernateSearch. Currently, we build complex ElasticSearch queries via combining multiple `QueryBuilder` objects created by separate methods like this:

```
protected QueryBuilder createSetQuery(String key, Set<?> values, boolean contains) {
    if (contains && !values.isEmpty()) {
        return QueryBuilders.termsQuery(key, values);
    } else if (!contains && Objects.nonNull(values)) {
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        return boolQuery.mustNot(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(key, values));
    } else {
        return QueryBuilders.matchQuery(key, 0);
    }
}
```

The returned `QueryBuilder` objects are then combined in calling methods via `BooleanQueryBuilder` objects like this:

```
...
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
boolQuery.must(createSetQuery(...);
...
```

Now I tried to migrate these methods to equivalent HibernateSearch methods like this, returning `SearchPredicate`s instead of `QueryBuilder`s (reading the HibernateSearch documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single I got the impression that is the closest match):

```
protected SearchPredicate createSetSearchPredicate(Class<?> clazz, SearchSession searchSession, String fieldName,
                                                   Set<?> fieldValues, boolean contains) {
    if (contains) {
        SearchScope<?> scope = searchSession.scope(clazz);
        SearchPredicateFactory factory = scope.predicate();
        return factory.terms().field( fieldName ).matchingAny( fieldValues ).toPredicate();
    } else {
        SearchScope<?> scope = searchSession.scope(clazz);
        SearchPredicateFactory factory = scope.predicate();
        return factory.bool().mustNot(factory.terms().field( fieldName ).matchingAny( fieldValues )).toPredicate();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is creating a `SearchPredicate` always seems to require a given Class and a HibernateSearch `SearchSession`. Is there any way to create such `SearchPredicate` instances *without* those two objects? In a similar "class agnostic" way as when building the ElasticSearch `QueryBuilder`s?

Currently, I have to either

- create the `SearchSession` in the outermost calling method and pass it together with a `Class` object through all intermediate methods until I reach those `SearchPredicate` creating methods or
- create the `SearchSession` object within each `SearchPredicate` creating method

My questions:

- is the later - creating `SearchSession` objects within each method - a problem? Do I have to make sure to reuse existing sessions or is `SearchSession` already a singleton and I do not have to worry about that?
- is there a way to create `SearchPredicate`s without `Class` and `SearchSession` objects, similar to how we created ElasticSearch `QueryBuilder` objects?
- is there a more approriate way to do what I am trying? Some other HibernateSearch class that would better fit as an replacement for the ombinable ElasticSearch `QueryBuilder` objects than `SearchPredicate`s?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at [this section of the reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl) to get an idea of how the Hibernate Search API is intended to be used.

You could just do this:

```java
protected List<MyEntity> myOuterMostMethod() {
    List<MyEntity> hits = searchSession.search( MyEntity.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool( b -> { 
            b.must( createSetSearchPredicate( f, "myField1",
                    Set.of( "val1", "val2" ), true ) );
            b.must( createSetSearchPredicate( f, "myField2",
                    Set.of( "val3", "val4" ), false ) );
        } ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 ); 
}


protected SearchPredicate createSetSearchPredicate(SearchPredicateFactory factory,
    String fieldName, Set<?> fieldValues, boolean contains) {
    if (contains) {
        return factory.terms()
                .field( fieldName ).matchingAny( fieldValues )
                .toPredicate();
    } else {
        return factory.bool().mustNot(factory.terms()
                .field( fieldName ).matchingAny( fieldValues ))
                .toPredicate();
    }
}
```

You can also do this, which is clearer in my opinion:

```java
protected List<MyEntity> myOuterMostMethod() {
    List<MyEntity> hits = searchSession.search( MyEntity.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool( b -> { 
            b.must( containAny( f, "myField1", Set.of( "val1", "val2" ) ) );
            b.mustNot( containAny( f, "myField2", Set.of( "val3", "val4" ) ) );
        } ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 ); 
}


protected SearchPredicate containAny(SearchPredicateFactory factory,
    String fieldName, Set<?> fieldValues) {
    return factory.terms().field( fieldName ).matchingAny( fieldValues ).toPredicate();
}
```

---

As to your questions:

> is the later - creating SearchSession objects within each method - a problem? Do I have to make sure to reuse existing sessions or is SearchSession already a singleton and I do not have to worry about that?

There is some level of caching behind the scenes, so performance-wise it shouldn't be too bad. But really, there's no need to re-create a `SearchSession` every time. Just grab the `SearchPredicateFactory` as shown in my example and pass that to your method.

> is there a way to create SearchPredicates without Class and SearchSession objects, similar to how we created ElasticSearch QueryBuilder objects?

Not really. Hibernate Search checks that the fields you reference actually exist, and it uses metadata to convert the values that you pass into JSON. It needs context in order to access that metadata, so it can't just create predicates from a static method call.

You can, however, create search predicates without a session. That gets rid of the requirement to have an open `EntityManager`/`Session` from Hibernate ORM, but you still need access to an `EntityManagerFactory`/`SessionFactory` (which contains the metadata Hibernate Search needs) and you still need to tell Hibernate Search which class you will target. Something like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = ...;
SearchScope<?> scope = Search.mapping(entityManagerFactory).scope(clazz);
SearchPredicateFactory factory = scope.predicate()
```

Also, if you really want to bypass Hibernate Search metadata, you can pass a [JSON query to Hibernate Search directly](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-extensions-elasticsearch-from-json).

> is there a more approriate way to do what I am trying? Some other HibernateSearch class that would better fit as an replacement for the ombinable ElasticSearch QueryBuilder objects than SearchPredicates?

The classes you're using are the right ones. I think you just need to make peace with the fact that Hibernate Search needs some context (a `SearchPredicateFactory` instance) to create a predicate, and does not offer static methods to create a predicate.